# Flutter how to get specific value from json http response

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using this code to upload json data to my nodejs server.

```
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  var data = createSamplePayment().toJson();
  var request = await client.openUrl('POST', Uri.parse(serverEndpoint + '/paymentrequests'));
  request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, 'APPLICATION/JSON');
  request.write(json.encode(data));
  var response = await request.close();
  String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  print(reply);
```

The output from print(reply) is:

```
flutter: {"url":"https://paymentrequests/86C0110D","token":"w8SWavZNjOG","id":"C3C4966AF64D8CE194F5E3C"}
```

But I only want to get ”token” value. What can I do to fix that? I have tried in many different ways without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DetailsModel {
  String url;
  String token;
  String id;

  DetailsModel({this.url, this.token, this.id});

  DetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    token = json['token'];
    id = json['id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['token'] = this.token;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Firstly, convert your response into a Model, to do that you would need the above code. Then map your response.

```
DetailsModel details = DetailsModel.fromJson(response);
```

Then to access the details you can simply use.

```
dynamic token = details.token; 
print(token); // w8SWavZNjOG
```

Comment: Okay, now i get this error: The argument type 'HttpClientResponse' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.",

Comment: Yeah, this is because you cannot assign a HttpClient Response to it.  Just  do this. 
`final Map response1  = json.decode(reply); ` and then instead of response pass response1 to fromJson method.

Comment: Okey. Where should I put that? Instead of DetailsModel details = DetailsModel.fromJson(response);?

Comment: yes, DetailsModel details = DetailsModel.fromJson(reply)

Comment: It looks like it doesn’t work beacuse reply is a string

Comment: Strange it should. final Map response1  = json.decode(response); print(response.toString); //? , Can you tell me what does this print of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223425/discussion-between-darsh-shah-and-mat-koffman).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use the following code to simulate this case
You can do `payloadFromJson(reply)` and `return payload.token` 
You can reference `Payload` class in full code 
code snippet

```
Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));
...
Future<String> postWithClientCertificate() async {
    ...
    Payload payload = payloadFromJson(reply);
    print(payload.token);
    return payload.token;
  }
```

output

```
I/flutter ( 5995): w8SWavZNjOG
I/flutter ( 5995): token w8SWavZNjOG
```

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  Payload({
    this.url,
    this.token,
    this.id,
  });

  String url;
  String token;
  String id;

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        url: json["url"],
        token: json["token"],
        id: json["id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url,
        "token": token,
        "id": id,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async{
    String token = await postWithClientCertificate();
    print("token $token");

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<String> postWithClientCertificate() async {
    /*final serverEndpoint = 'https://1991269db78887f9e.ngrok.io';
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var data = createSamplePayment().toJson();
    var request = await client.openUrl('POST', Uri.parse(serverEndpoint + '/paymentrequests'));
    request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, 'APPLICATION/JSON');
    request.write(json.encode(data));
    var response = await request.close();
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    print(reply);*/

    String reply =
        '''{"url":"https://paymentrequests/86C0110D","token":"w8SWavZNjOG","id":"C3C4966AF64D8CE194F5E3C"}''';

    Payload payload = payloadFromJson(reply);

    print(payload.token);
    return payload.token;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```